# ts2322 Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<undefined>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<MyType | undefined>>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, cordova-plugin-purchase

I'm having trouble writing a wrapper for `useState()` because I'm getting an error I don't understand:

> Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction>' is not assignable to type
> 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<VerifiedPurchase | undefined>>'.

> Type 'SetStateAction<VerifiedPurchase | undefined>' is not assignable to
> type 'SetStateAction'.

> Type  'VerifiedPurchase' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction'.

> Type 'VerifiedPurchase' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.

Here's my code:

```
const useStateIAPSubscription = (): [
  CdvPurchase.VerifiedPurchase | undefined,
  React.Dispatch<
    React.SetStateAction<CdvPurchase.VerifiedPurchase | undefined>
  >,
] => {
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(undefined);
  return [subscription, setSubscription];
};

export default useStateIAPSubscription;
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a `useState()` hook with a default value of `undefined`.  I want the setState() function to only accept `undefined` or a specific type (`CdvPurchase.VerifiedPurchase`).

I'm trying to do it this way because the app is initialized before the subscription is ready, and I want to add it later with `useState()`.

How can I fix this TypeScript error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState(undefined);
```

Since you haven't specified what type of data this state will contain, typescript does its best to infer it. It sees that the initial value is `undefined` so it assumes the state is (and always will be) `undefined`.

Since you want it to be able to change to a non-undefined value, you'll need to provide an explicit type, as in:

```
const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState<CdvPurchase.VerifiedPurchase | undefined>(undefined);
```